# How do I configure SqlServer for BCP on linux?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have my client on linux and my server on Windows.  The functionality I need is to run BCP with the option -T to use automated authentication.  This works with my account from Windows and Linux but fails with the automated build user on Linux (it does not run on Windows).

I have manually cloned my user and login attributes fot the build user but it does not work.  I keep getting the error:

> [DB][139693847296160] DB: HY000: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11
>   for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Key has been revoked

I have also tried setting the build user as a login on SqlServer and mapping it to a new build user on the database.  This user owns every schema and is a member of every role on the table.  However, the error is the same.

Is there some other configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: I assume you have gone for the (long) task of configuring Kerberos on your Linux Server and that you therefore authenticate to your terminal, on the Linux server, using your Windows Domain account?

Comment: Adding the the comment by @Larnu, see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#authenticating-a-linux-or-macos-computer-with-active-directory).